# Indexing attachment fails silently, no errors anywhere but not indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to index a powerpoint using the attachment plugin. We have indexed I would say hundreds of attachments to this point without any issue. This attachment, for whatever reason, will not index. There's no error logged in the cluster.log, and nothing that I can see in any other logs from apache et al.

Is there any way to diagnose what's going on? The file is 42 mb in size and we're running ES 1.1. I'm running Tika 1.5 it seems, which I downloaded and dropped the file into, and it seems to parse it fine.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest Apache Tika release, currently 1.7?

Comment: @Gagravarr if it parses with 1.5, why would I need to upgrade to 1.7?

Comment: There have been lots of bugs fixed in Tika 1.6 and 1.7, it's possible one of those could be the cause. Additionally, it's much easier to get people to take an interest in bugs if you're on the latest version!